# Call to a member function isVirtual() on null magento2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.6

I have some product condition that need to be validate by core validate() function, I am using plugin here to restrict free shipping method if certain conditions are there in the cart.

```
public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $carrierCode,
    $request
) {
    $allItems = $request->getAllItems();

    $ruleCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 1]);

    foreach ($allItems as $item) {    
        $_product = $this->product->create()->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
        foreach ($ruleCollection as $rule) {
           if($rule->getConditions()->validate($_product)){
              if $carrierCode == 'freeshipping') {
                 return false;
              }
           }
        }
    }           
    $result = $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
    return $result;
}
```

I need to validate custom rule but I am getting Error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on null issue.
Plz let me know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to check if $item is not null before accessing its methods.

Check this updated code,

```
public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $carrierCode,
    $request
) {
    $allItems = $request->getAllItems();

    $ruleCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 1]);

    foreach ($allItems as $item) {    
         if ($item === null) {
                  continue; // skip to next iteration if item is null
              }
    
        $_product = $this->product->create()->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
        foreach ($ruleCollection as $rule) {
           if($rule->getConditions()->validate($_product)){
              if $carrierCode == 'freeshipping') {
                 return false;
              }
           }
        }
    }           
    $result = $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working, I have already tried this solution.
I am getting issue in this way. Error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on null in
vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address.php:177

Comment: @AbhayAgrawal same issue here. Did you find a solution please?

Comment: @G.G. Yes I have solved the issue

Comment: @G.G. I am not getting any specific product information, I am validating some shipping rule, it is working as per the above comment

Comment: @AbhayAgrawal not working on my end. Can you help me with my code please?

Comment: @G.G. Plz add your code in comment if possible then I will check

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($allItems as $item) {  
foreach ($ruleCollection as $rule) {
    if($rule->getConditions()->validate($item)) {
        if (in_array($carrierCode, $disableShippingMethod)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}